# How to make the list active then it will not apply in the console in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

***TS***

```
activeFilter = {
    filterBy: 'Application',
    length: 100,
    status: '',
    order: 'ASC',
    grouped: false
  };


  ngOnInit() {

  }

  handleFilter(targetFilter?: string, value?: any, idx?: any) {
    this.activeFilter[targetFilter] = value;


    if (this.activeFilter[targetFilter] === 'ACK') {
      this.activeFilter['ack'] = true;
    } else {
      this.activeFilter['ack'] = '';
    }

    console.log('/api?length=100&status='+this.activeFilter['status']+'&ack='+this.activeFilter['ack']);
  }
```

**HTML***

```
 <nz-dropdown
      class="filter-dropdown"
      [nzTrigger]="'click'"
      nzPlacement="bottomRight"
    >
      <a nz-dropdown nz-tooltip>
        {{ activeFilter.filterBy }}
        <i nz-icon [type]="activeFilter.order === 'ASC' ? 'up' : 'down'"></i>
      </a>
      <ul nz-menu>
        <li class="filter-dropdown-item" nz-menu-item (click)="handleFilter('status', '')">All
          <i nz-icon nzType="check" *ngIf="activeFilter.status==''" nzTheme="outline"></i>
        </li>
        <li class="filter-dropdown-item" nz-menu-item (click)="handleFilter('status', 'ACK')">Acknowledged
          <i nz-icon nzType="check" *ngIf="activeFilter.status=='ACK'" nzTheme="outline"></i>
        </li>
        <li class="filter-dropdown-item" nz-menu-item (click)="handleFilter('status', 'READ')">Read
          <i nz-icon nzType="check" *ngIf="activeFilter.status=='READ'" nzTheme="outline"></i>
        </li>
        <li class="filter-dropdown-item" nz-menu-item (click)="handleFilter('status', 'NEW')">New
          <i nz-icon nzType="check" *ngIf="activeFilter.status=='NEW'" nzTheme="outline"></i>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nz-dropdown>
```

Here's the output: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6zvbjl-mz7bmy?file=src/app/app.component.ts

The problem is when I clicked the Acknowledged in the console it should be like this.
`/api?length=100&status=&ack=true` it should be empty but it the check on the dropdown should be active and without adding a new variable. my problem is when I click the Acknowledge the output in console is `/api?length=100&status=ACK&ack=true` which its not my expected output.

my expected output in console should be like this `/api?length=100&status=&ack=true` and on the dropdown group list should be like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
handleFilter(targetFilter?: string, value?: any, idx?: any) {
  // Here you are setting activeFilter.status = 'ACK'
  this.activeFilter[targetFilter] = value;
  ..
  // So the api call would get the same.
  // If you want other behaviour, you can use the value variable or any other to hold the updated string
  if (value === 'ACK') {
    this.activeFilter['ack'] = true;
    value = '';
  } else {
    this.activeFilter['ack'] = '';
  }
  console.log('/api?length=100&status='+value+'&ack='+this.activeFilter['ack']);
}
```

New outputs:

When Acknowledge clicked => /api?length=100&status=&ack=true

When others clicked => /api?length=100&status=READ&ack=

Comment: how the acknowledge should be active?

Comment: By active, if you mean the tick mark, then isn't it already active. Because activeFilter.status would still be equal to 'ACK', and Acknowledge would still show the tick mark. Try the posted code and let us know if it works or not.